# MySQLi insert into prepare error

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I inserted a lot of stuff into a mysql databse.

But now I get an error in the prepare statement. I see Database prepare error. What am I doing wrong?

This is my Code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
                Contact (IP,To,Name,Email,Subject,Text)
            VALUES 
                ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
           ";

    if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
        echo 'Database prepare error';
        exit;
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $ip_contact, $to_contact, $name_contact, $email_contact, $subject_contact, $text_contact);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo 'Database execute error';
        exit;
    }

    $stmt->close();
```

My SQL table looks like this:

```
Contact:
- ID    int(11)    auto_increment    primary key
- IP    varchar(15)
- To    varchar(5)
- Name    varchar(20)
- Email    varchar(20)
- Subject    varchar(20)
- Text    varchar(600)
```

Comment: What does [`$db->error`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example `to` is a [reserved word in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you should change your code to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
            `Contact` (`IP`,`To`,`Name`,`Email`,`Subject`,`Text`)
        VALUES 
            ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
       ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly To is a reserved word in mysql, so you need to use it using quotes as defined [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Secondly you need to set the values of variables before calling execute method.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
            Contact (IP,'To',Name,Email,Subject,Text)
        VALUES 
            ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
       ";

if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    echo 'Database prepare error';
    exit;
}

$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $ip_contact, $to_contact, $name_contact, $email_contact, $subject_contact, $text_contact);

$ip_contact = '123456';
$to_contact = '123456';
$name_contact = '12345';
$email_contact = '1111';
$subject_contact = 'test';
$text_contact = 'test';


if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo 'Database execute error';
    exit;
}

$stmt->close();
```

Now check, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

`To` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You must add backticks around it:

```
Contact (IP,`To`,Name,Email
```